# Why is my browser changing background-position when I scroll?

Tags: html, css, jekyll

I have a GitHub pages site here: https://steven-murray.github.io/code/ which I made with Jekyll / [type-on-strap](https://github.com/sylhare/Type-on-Strap) theme. The top banner image has a color overlay to make the text more readable. However, the overlay changes position relative to the url image itself when scrolling down, which makes a very ugly tear.

I've set `background-position: center, top;`, which you can see when you first open the page. However, upon scrolling, the `background-position` is somehow automatically changed to have a negative offset, which is causing the weird tear.

How can I get it to just sit in the one place?

Comment: Please make this a [mcve] by including the necessary code within the question itself.

Comment: Anyways, the issue is caused by https://github.com/steven-murray/steven-murray.github.io/blob/main/assets/js/main.min.js . If you prettify the code, you'll see that there's a scroll listener that changes the backgroundPosition style.

Comment: Ah, I see! Thank you so much, that absolutely fixed it!